# SQL scalar subquery checking a row was found

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, cardinality, scalar-subquery

**Introduction**

Sometimes instead of a join you can deliberately use a scalar subquery to check that not more than one row was found.  For example you might have this query to look up nationality for some `person` rows.

`select p.name,
       c.iso
from person p
join person_country_map pcm
  on p.id = pcm.person
join country c
  on pcm.country = c.id
where p.id in (1, 2, 3)`

Now, suppose that the `person_country_map` is not a functional mapping.  A given person may map to more than one country - so the join may find more than one row.  Or indeed, a person might not be in the mapping table at all, at least as far as any database constraints are concerned.

But for *this particular query* I happen to know that the persons I am querying will have exactly one country.  That is the assumption I am basing my code on.  But I would like to check that assumption where possible - so that if something went wrong and I end up trying to do this query for a person with more than one country, or with no country mapping row, it will die.

**Adding a safety check for at most one row**

To check for more than one row, you can rewrite the join as a scalar subquery:

`select p.name,
       (
         select c.iso
         from person_country_map pcm
         join country c
           on pc.country = c.id
         where pcm.person = p.id
       ) as iso
from person p
where p.id in (1, 2, 3)`

Now the DBMS will give an error if a person queried maps to two or more countries.  It won't return multiple entries for the same person, as the straightforward join would.  So I can sleep a bit easier knowing that this error case is being checked for even before any rows are returned to the application.  As a careful programmer I might check in the application as well, of course.

**Is it possible to have a safety check for** *no* **row found?**

But what about if there is no row in person_country_map for a person?  The scalar subquery will return null in that case, making it roughly equivalent to a left join.

(For the sake of argument assume a foreign key from person_country_map.country to country.id and a unique index on country.id so that particular join will always succeed and find exactly one country row.)

**My question**

Is there some way I can express in SQL that I want one and exactly one result?  A plain scalar subquery is 'zero or one'.  I would like to be able to say

`select 42, (select exactly one x from t where id = 55)`

and have the query fail at runtime if the subquery wouldn't return a row.  Of course, the above syntax is fictional and I am sure it wouldn't be that easy.

I am using MSSQL 2008 R2, and in fact this code is in a stored procedure, so I can use TSQL if necessary.  (Obviously ordinary declarative SQL is preferable since that can be used in view definitions too.)  Of course, I can do an `exists` check, or I can select a value into a TSQL variable and then explicitly check it for nullness, and so on.  I could even select results into a temporary table and then build unique indexes on that table as a check.  But is there no more readable and elegant way to mark my assumption that a subquery returns exactly one row, and have that assumption checked by the DBMS?

Comment: Have you considered a user-defined function that throws an exception if there is not exactly one result?

Comment: @HABO, do you mean a general check_not_null(x) function which returns x if x is not null, and barfs (by triggering a division by zero, say) otherwise?

Comment: I was thinking of `GetCountryForUser( UserId )`. It either returns the unique `CountryId` for the specified user or complains. Unfortunately, `RaIsError` and `Throw` are not allowed in UDFs, hence you are left with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485034/how-to-report-an-error-from-a-sql-server-user-defined-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSSQL it appears that `isnull` only evaluates its second argument if the first is null.  So in general you can say

`select isnull(x, 0/0)`

to give a query which returns `x` if non-null and dies if that would give null.  Applying this to a scalar subquery,

`select 42, isnull((select x from t where id = 55), 0/0)`

will guarantee that exactly one row is found by the `select x` subquery.  If more than one, the DBMS itself will produce an error; if no row, the division by zero is triggered.

Applying this to the original example leads to the code

`select p.name,
       -- Get the unique country code of this person.
       -- Although the database constraints do not guarantee it in general,
       -- for this particular query we expect exactly one row.  Check that.
       --
       isnull((
         select c.iso
         from person_country_map pcm
         join country c
           on pc.country = c.id
         where pcm.person = p.id
       ), 0/0) as iso
from person p
where p.id in (1, 2, 3)`

For a better error message you can use a conversion failure instead of division by zero:

`select 42, isnull((select x from t where id = 55), convert(int, 'No row found'))`

although that will need further `convert` shenanigans if the value you are fetching from the subquery is not itself an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this harder than it needs to be

For sure you need a FK relationship on  person.id to person_country_map.person

You either have unique constraint on person_country_map.person or you don't?
If you don't have a unique constraint then yes you can have multiple records for the same person_country_map.person.

If you want to know if you have any duplicate then

```
select pcm.person 
from person_country_map pcm
group by  pcm.person  
having count(*) > 1
```

If there is more than one then you just need to determine which one

```
select p.name,
       min(c.iso)
from person p
join person_country_map pcm
  on p.id = pcm.person
join country c
  on pcm.country = c.id 
where p.id in (1, 2, 3)
group by p.name
```

Comment: There is no unique constraint on person_country_map.person because *in general*, a person can belong to more than one country.  But *for this specific application*, I know that I am only querying people who belong to one.  The example schema and query are invented to illustrate the general point of wanting to check a scalar subquery returns exactly one row, because database constraints do not guarantee it, although I as the programmer believe it will always be the case.

Comment: It's not an answer to my question, which was how you can make an SQL scalar subquery which checks exactly one result was returned.  The example `person` schema is only something I invented to illustrate that question.  The query that returns `min(c.iso)` is one technique, which I have used in the past, but in the event more than one row is found, I do not want to determine which one; I want the query to fail with a big fat error so that I can find out what's wrong with my assumptions.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more explicit that the schema is only invented to illustrate a general point.  I have edited the question text.