# Error Handling in SQL UDF

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am creating a UDF in SQL Server. I can not use try-catch block in a user defined function. How can I handle an exception or error in UDF?

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_POLICY_NO
(@POLICYID nvarchar(15))
 RETURNS varchar(30)
 AS
 BEGIN
 declare @Return varchar(30)
 select @return = (SELECT POLICY_NO FROM tblPolicy WHERE POLICY_ID = @POLICYID)
return @return
 end
```

Although tblPolicy is Not exist, it will through error. How can I handle like SP?

Comment: better to paste your code here, cannot help without looking into your code... and why cannot you use try and catch block?

Comment: @long Added Code in Question.

Comment: can you take a try with my answer

Comment: What's the point creating a function which will always fail?

Comment: the above code is just for example. it's not my requirement. actually this question was asked in an Interview. "How can I handle errors. in Udf"

Answer (score 2):

You should check  **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240541/error-handling-in-user-defined-functions)** for some answers

And also I have some suggestions:

1. Since you cant print or use try catch blocks inside a function , use a stored procedure instead, although I dont think you can catch the "*Invalid object name 'tblPolicy'* " error. I suggest checking if the table exists and then perform your query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the above code is just for example. it's not my requirement. actually this question was asked in an Interview. "How can I handle errors. in Udf"

Comment: @SurajKMad I understand, but it was a little misleading and also there is a lot of info regarding this topic that I`m sure you could've found before asking the question! Cheers