# Nested Transaction in a loop can not committed nor rolled back to savepoint in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following function that reads JSON files and parses them. Sometimes these files are not correct and so I don't want to take them. I tried to handle the problem with a `try catch`.

```sql
...
OPEN cursor_id;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO  @ID,@Data;
BEGIN TRAN INNEN

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY 
        SAVE TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN
        INSERT INTO EinzelObjekteGeparst WITH (TABLOCK HOLDLOCK)
            (docid, [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue], POS1,POS2,POS3,POS4,POS5,POS6,POS7,POS8,POS9,POS10,POS11,POS12)
                                        SELECT  @ID , [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue], POS1,POS2,POS3,POS4,POS5,POS6,POS7,POS8,POS9,POS10,POS11,POS12  from dbo.JSONPathsAndValues(@Data) 
        COMMIT TRAN INNENKLEIN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            @ID AS DocID,
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
            XACT_State() as  XACT_State,
            @@TRANCOUNT  as TRANCOUNT

            IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN
            IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1   COMMIT TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN

            PRINT '>> ERROR docid ' + cast(@ID as nvarchar) + ' Rollback'
    END CATCH

END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The parsing fails with the following error

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 15
> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '<' is found
> at position 0.

This is what I want to handle.
Currently I already know, that this error/insert not trigger `XACT_State` being <> -1 and this cause the following error

> Msg 3931, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.ParseEinzelObjekte, Line 65
> [Batch Start Line 18] The current transaction cannot be committed and
> cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire
> transaction.

I also tried double nested `try catch` and explicitly generated errors to trigger `XACT_State`. That did not work either.

I need a solution handle the json error but only skip (Rollback) the faulty entry.

Comment: Test the string with [`isjson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) first? Also you don't `fetch` from the loop, so it executes at most once (which is good because otherwise you would have over-committed the transaction).

Comment: i just fetch it. isjson is an option but realy slow. Run this as one batch is also not possible (to many files) but i commit all 10000 files/json

Answer (score 0):

[`COMMIT TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has an optional parameter `transaction_name`, but it is ignored by the SQL Server Database Engine.

Your code should have only one `COMMIT TRAN` after the whole loop. It is not possible to commit part of the transaction. You can only rollback part of the transaction. So, inside the loop you should be able to rollback to the savepoint.

So, remove both calls to `COMMIT TRAN INNENKLEIN` in your code.
And add another call to

```
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO  @ID,@Data;
```

inside the loop right before the end. The way it is written now, it will process the first row from the cursor over and over again.

```
...
OPEN cursor_id;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO  @ID,@Data;
BEGIN TRAN INNEN

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY 
        SAVE TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN
        INSERT INTO EinzelObjekteGeparst WITH (TABLOCK HOLDLOCK)
            (docid, [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue], POS1,POS2,POS3,POS4,POS5,POS6,POS7,POS8,POS9,POS10,POS11,POS12)
        SELECT  @ID , [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue], POS1,POS2,POS3,POS4,POS5,POS6,POS7,POS8,POS9,POS10,POS11,POS12  from dbo.JSONPathsAndValues(@Data) 

        -- remove this
        -- COMMIT TRAN INNENKLEIN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            @ID AS DocID,
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
            XACT_State() as  XACT_State,
            @@TRANCOUNT  as TRANCOUNT

            -- rollback to the savepoint
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN

            -- remove this
            --IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1   COMMIT TRANSACTION  INNENKLEIN

            PRINT '>> ERROR docid ' + cast(@ID as nvarchar) + ' Rollback'
    END CATCH
    
    -- add this
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_id INTO  @ID,@Data;
END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: thanks for the hint with the missing second fetch. I removed it by mistake to make the posting more clear.

Comment: your solution with one commit would be also my prefred solution. In this case it would not work because XACT_State is -1. this lead to "The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction".

Comment: can not add readable Links so instead : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/xact-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Well, then this means that the `dbo.JSONPathsAndValues` function generates an error of such severity that a partial rollback is not possible. I'd suggest to ask another question that would show the code of `dbo.JSONPathsAndValues` and ask how to parse JSON in such as way that would allow to catch the error and rollback transaction to a savepoint. Meanwhile, have a thorough look at all three parts of the [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server by Erland Sommarskog](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html). There is a lot to read and learn about error handling in SQL Server.

Comment: the JSONPathsAndValues function is an inline function. The error handling is very limited

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240541/error-handling-in-user-defined-functions

Comment: I will probably not get around to implementing it with '''isjson as GSerg suggested. This will be nice and slow

Answer (score 0):

For this stuff, i would remove all transaction code, create a @t-variable, do the inserts in a loop to the @t-variable, and just do one big insert to the real table at the end wrapped in a transaction if you really need it (i'm not sure why).

Comment: the main idea was to get ride of faulty json files (using try catch in combination of transactions). the json convert function is  a inline function, so not very handy. your solution would fix the problem with  transactions but will cause a huge io impact (900k files, sum 200 GB)

Comment: It seems you want fast, good and little IO. I have a feeling you only can get two =)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you should just remove the transaction handling altogether.

If you want to insert all the JSON in one go, you can simply use one big `INSERT`. Just use `ISJSON` to check the JSON is valid before parsing.

```sql
INSERT INTO EinzelObjekteGeparst WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
    (docid, [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue],
     POS1, POS2, POS3, POS4, POS5, POS6, POS7, POS8, POS9, POS10, POS11, POS12)
SELECT
    t.ID , [element_id], [Depth], [Thepath], [ValueType], [TheValue],
    POS1, POS2, POS3, POS4, POS5, POS6, POS7, POS8, POS9, POS10, POS11, POS12  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE ISJSON(t.Data) = 1
) t
CROSS APPLY dbo.JSONPathsAndValues(t.Data) j;
```

If you want to avoid blowing out your transaction log then you can continue using a cursor, but you should still remove all the transaction handling. If you have the whole thing in a transaction then it would come out to the same result  as above anyway, so it makes no sense to use one in that case.

`SAVE TRANSACTION` does not help with keeping the transaction log under control: the outer transaction is still held open.

You can avoid the errors still by using `ISJSON` to check for incorrect JSON data.